# Amazon Quicksight Calculated Fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I'm having a problem with what should be a very simple calculated field. I have two conversion numbers, let's say a "7 day click" number and a "1 day view" number.

I'm trying to create a calculated field that simply adds these two numbers together.
[image: calculated field setting]

Yet, this is the result I'm getting:
[image]

As we can see, the all conv value is not simply adding the other two columns. What am I doing wrong in the calculated field?

Thanks in advance, as I've spent way too much time trying to figure out such a simple thing

EDIT:
It appears that, when I add a new grouping, that the problem consists of null values in one of the two columns. example:
[image]

How can I change the calculated field to account for this? In the data warehouse, these blank values are just null values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried out what You did and it works fine for me:

[QuickSight Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eClhS.png)

[Calculated field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRvLE.png)

I suppose there is something wrong with Your dataset.
Probably the granularity of the date field is not day but something else like hour and the calculated field tries to add eg. 11 Jun 10:00 + 12 Jun 11:00.
This is of course wrong. You need to add 11 Jun + 12 Jun.

Probably You need to extract the day of Yours date field.

Answer (score 0):

to my question about the calculated field, this was what I used that worked.

ifelse( isNull({conv_1dv}), 0, {conv_1dv}) + ifelse(isNull({conv_7dc}),0,{conv_7dc})